# What are best practices for Apache Karaf feature

Tags: apache-karaf

Are there any known best practices or projects to look into for an example of Apache Karaf feature?

All I has found is the official documentation: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/latest/#_feature_and_resolver

But it is not covering common usage examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are the guiding principals I defined for our consulting practice:

1. Have your features.xml file process as a filtered resource in maven so you can do version substitution, etc.
2. Depend on semantic version ranges, not specific versions as much as possible
3. Specify start-levels
4. Create a single *features repository* (features.xml) for a business domain -- ie Ordering, Billing, Quoting, etc.
5. Create a separate *feature* for API vs implementation
6. Specify a 'capability' when defining an implementation feature
7. Have dependent features (features that depend on features) depend on the API feature and specify a 'requirement' that is satisfied by an implementation that specifies a 'capability')

This allows you to swap implementations without re-defining features, and features that depend on other features